# using SET in VBscript command

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I'm trying to run an VBscript which runs a command line statement that contains the word `set` in the cmd line command. 
The VBscript is recognizing it as a reserved word and giving the error:

> Expected ')'

The command I'm trying to run in VBScript is:

```
objShell.Run(appcmd set config /section:isapiFilters /-[name='JakartaXAPI'])
```

How can I escape the reserved word?

Comment: Strings need to be in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Expected ')'` is simply a **syntax error**.

`Run` method requires its first argument to be a [string subtype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf(v=vs.84).aspx) and given space-delimited word sequence  can't be reckoned for a *string*. You need to  enclose it in quotation marks (`" "`).

[Run Method (Windows Script Host)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx)

> Runs a program in a new process.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
> ```
>
> Arguments
>
> - `object` WshShell object.
> - `strCommand` String value indicating the command line you want to run. You must include any parameters you want to pass to the
>     executable file.
> - `intWindowStyle` Optional. Integer value indicating the appearance of the program's window. Note that not all programs make use of this
>     information.
> - `bWaitOnReturn` Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for the program to finish executing before
>     continuing to the next statement in your script. If set to true,
>     script execution halts until the program finishes, and Run returns any
>     error code returned by the program. If set to false (the default), the
>     Run method returns immediately after starting the program,
>     automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code).

Use

```
objShell.Run "appcmd set config /section:isapiFilters /-[name='JakartaXAPI']"
```

or

```
appcmd = "path\to\someapp.exe"
objShell.Run appcmd & " set config /section:isapiFilters /-[name='JakartaXAPI']"
```

Comment: Really? They just didn't pass the command to `Run()` as a string which is causing the VBScript runtime to error, not rocket science. [@Noodles already mentioned this over 2 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427824/using-set-in-vbscript-command#comment62360285_37427824).

Comment: @Lankymart yes, really. `Expected ')'` is _compilation_ not _runtime_ error.

Comment: And your point is? I didn't say it's a runtime error I said the "VBScript Runtime" *(referring to the script engine)* errors, your just being pedantic. Still think this answer has little bearing on the actual issue...`Option Explicit` and `On Error Goto 0` would not stop this error from happening *(you said it yourself, it's a Compilation Error)* or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lankymart My point is…  to help questioners by answering questions _the best way I know_ (and I endeavour to follow [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) article as well as the hint in _empty_ comment window: _…avoid answering questions in comments_). Moreover,  meeting a confessed `VBScript` beginner, I always advise to use `Option Explicit` and `On Error Goto 0`. Maybe clumsily like [Cato the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cato_the_Elder)'s [_Ceterum autem censeo Carthaginem esse delendam_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthago_delenda_est).

Comment: It doesn't need an answer it's off topic *(simple typography error)* it just needs to be closed.